# Helping user input correct format into EditFor

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My SQL database has a column `Date` which allows strings only in such format: `__/____`, basically month/year for example: `01/2019`.

Is it possible for my:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

to have some helper so that user can type only using the correct format? For example the editor which has strong typed something like this: `__/___` and can only input numbers to fill underscores.

Comment: If you changed your database and model to store a date rather than a string (which I would advise anyway), I think you could use the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36014557/1048425).

Comment: The data format for the field in user interface and data storage can be independant . You should show the date in the users locale and convert to the format before saving to database

Comment: Would this help: `<input type="month">`? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month)

Comment: @Alex not so much because SQL stores the value as nvarchar in such format.

Comment: @GarethD if I change the datatype to `DateTime` will I be able to use @Alex approach to input `month` for it?

Comment: @Pomme read the linked page. It explains near the bottom that the control's value is a string in `yyyy-MM` form. A far better form than `MM/yyyy` as it can handle ordering, range queries etc. If you want to convert it to `MM/yyyy` you can use a regex or string manipulation to switch the parts

Comment: @Pomme besides, you don't have a date to begin with, just a string. Date types in SQL have no format, nor can they store just a month without a day.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, 
    new { @Value = Model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), @class="datepicker" })
```